# Address Symbol Table in Basic Computer

Tags: assembly, mano-machine

I can't understand how we get the Hexadecimal code of the labels in the address symbol table.

[Program To subtract 2 numbers]

```
     ORG 100
     LDA SUB
     CMA
     INC
     ADD MIN 
     STA DIF
     HLT
MIN, DEC 83
SUB, DEC -23
DIF, HEX 0
     END
```

The address symbol table of the previous program:

[image: Scan of address symbol table]

Comment: Uh, about a million people have a Google drive named `#my-drive`.

Answer (score -1):

Googled around a bit; found the answer on page 13 of [this PDF titled "Programming the Basic computer"](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mperkows/CLASS_573/573_2007/luento8.pdf):

- MIN = 106
- SUB = 107
- DIF = 108

Note: if the link above ever becomes broken (as happened to the [docstoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstoc) link I originally proposed), then just google for "Programming the Basic computer", as there are plenty of similar documents, mostly on university websites.

Comment: Please, open the image in my Google drive!

Comment: Thanks, we can see the image now. Seems perfectly clear to me; I see the symbols in ASCII (e.g. `MIN,`), and their addresses as 16-bit binary numbers (e.g. `01 06`). Exactly as I presented them to you in my answer above (OK, except for the leading zero). Just what is puzzling you?

Comment: OMG,THANKS I didn't know it was the equivalent values in ASCII.

Comment: You're welcome. Just out of curiosity, is this the *Mano Machine*? Looks like a nice tutorial for computer architecture, is it?

Comment: Yes it's. I'm using "Computer System Architecture book by Morris Mano" for self-study.